# How to pass a nid to panel, and load a node with the given nid as context?

Tags: panels

The panel has a custom path, Like this: http://example.com/mypanel/something/theNID/something_else

So the arguments to the panel are:

1. something
2. theNID
3. something_else.

How can I load a node with some variable nid (*theNID* in this case), and have it available as a `context` in the panel, and then, make all of it's fields accessible directly in that panel?

If I create a view and load the node (with *theNID*) within the view, the view won't pass the loaded node as context to panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Settings -> Basic -> Path -> something/%node/something_else
2. Settings -> Arguments -> Change ->  Content: ID

Then at 'Variants -> Contexts' you should see the loaded 'Argument 1'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: For sending panel an argument, A % sign must be used, And just using panel option "Path string from URL" or something like that is NOT the fun/right way, Instead, The path should be:  http://exmaple.com/something/%nid/%what

Then panel will ask what %nid is, Saying it's a node, Panel will load it as an available context automatically.

Short Answer: Use %nid instead of nid when choosing panel path on panel setting form.